# Scrapy Spider Webpage Extraction

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract data from Webpage(https://www.cato.org/research/34/commentary) though python. It contains links to an article and from that particular article I have to extract date, author and article headline.And I have repeat same operation to all the article.

I am able to extract document title from this command:

```
response.css('h1.page-h1::text').extract()
```

and to follow article link:

```
response.css('p.text-large.experts-more-h' > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

But how do I do for all the links? Please help I am new to this.

Comment: Try `.extract()` instead of `.extract_first()`

Comment: you asked the same question a day ago ...

Comment: @paultrmbrth I tried .extract() but in vain ,can you please try it. Yes Umair I did but didn't get the solution. Please help if you can it's really important.

Comment: In your question, please detail how you tried `.extract()`, what you got as result, why is wasn't what you expected.

Comment: When I am trying to extract Article Title I am able to do it but nothing is working for date and author.  Output is coming just as -----    [ ]

Here is the webpage : https://www.cato.org/publications/commentary/we-have-no-idea-universal-preschool-actually-helps-kids

Comment: @SarwarHayatt, putting all that information into the question increases the odds of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
for art in response.css('p.text-large.experts-more-h' > a'):
  art.css("::attr(href)").extract_first()
```

Comment: Can you help me with a python file? Which extracts date and author.